# Crash on EXT4-FS

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, ssd, crash, ext4

I have a Dell Precision 5510 with a NVME PCIe SSD with Ubuntu 16.04 and sometimes, I don't know when exactly, the file system falls or something similar and everything I can get from the laptop are messages on the screen(after pressing ALT + CTRL + F1) like:

> [4433.524427] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3):
> __ext4_get_inode_loc:4043: inode #1319902: block 5243485: comm NetworkManager: unable to read itable block
>
> [4433.526047] EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3):
> __ext4_get_inode_loc:4043: inode #1319902: block 5243485: comm polkitd: unable to read itable block

And more like shown above.
I have had this "crash" or "fall" more than 5 times. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but this still happens.
I have also installed Windows 10 in the laptop, and I haven't had any kind of crash related to the file system or the SSD.
Does anyone know what is happening here? Is it a problem of my SSD or is it a problem of Ubuntu's drivers for NVME PCIe SSDs?

Thank you so much

Below there's more information of the system:

```
$ sudo blkid

/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="fcaf1a0f" PTTYPE="dos" 
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="System Reserved Partition" UUID="986E08516E082B18" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="fcaf1a0f-01" 
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="01D244BB898084C0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="fcaf1a0f-02"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="e4ef92b3-58f2-4756-8ed9-8889361265d7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fcaf1a0f-03" 
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="6c86d12a-556f-47b4-921a-7540c0771fe6" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="fcaf1a0f-05" 
/dev/sda: LABEL="MYLINUXLIVE" UUID="9619-6EDB" TYPE="vfat"

$ cat /etc/fstab

UUID=e4ef92b3-58f2-4756-8ed9-8889361265d7 /  ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1 
UUID=6c86d12a-556f-47b4-921a-7540c0771fe6 none swap    sw   0       0
```

> ~$ dpkg -l *microcode*
> ||/ Name                    Version           Architecture
> Description
>
> ii  intel-microcode           3.20151106.1      amd64
> Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
>
> un  microcode.ctl          none         none         (no description
> available)

Comment: Do you know how to boot into recovery mode and run fsck?

Comment: Yes, I have already run fsck on the device and it reports "clean". I don't think it's a corrupted file system, because I have installed ubuntu twice and I get the same problem. I think it's another cause, like problems with the driver's NVME SSD or a SSD's problem. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Edit your question to include the output, in terminal, of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Do you have Intel processors? Also give me the output of `dpkg -l *microcode*`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Everything looks normal. Do you use Windows? Do you have any software installed there that allows you to read Ubuntu EXT4 partitions (which Windows can't do on its own).

Comment: I have also installed Windows 10 on another partition and no, I don't have any kind of software to read EXT4 partitions. What do you think it is happening here? Do you know about any kind of incompatibility between M.2 SSD's and Ubuntu? Thank you for the answers

Comment: I don't know. You might try running the SMART diagnostics on the SSD and see if it'll find anything. Install `gsmartcontrol` to do this, if you haven't already.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the SSD. It says "Unknown Model". Thank you very much for everything

Comment: Unknown model just means that the drive is not in the built-in drive database. The SMART stuff should still work. Give it another try.