# Thinkpad T14 AMD gen2 ext4-fs error

Tags: kernel, thinkpad, ext4, amd-processor, nvme

Hello I bought new Thinkpad T14 AMD with Ryzen 5850U and unable to properly use Ubuntu on it.

My steps:

1. Shrink existing Windows 10
2. Install Ubuntu in one single partition (ext4, no ecryption, swap, etc)
3. Install loader to drive (dual-boot is working)
4. Install Xubuntu 20 LTS usb-drive (I used same for installing this system to my other 2 laptops)
5. I found that existing 5.4.x kernel is not working with screen brightness and AMD hardware (wrong frequency in lcpu, for example), not usable at all
6. Upgrade to modern kernels with Mainline Kernel installed, 5.16.12 works fine with hardware except for errors
7. After some working, even light working. I get many EXT4-fs error that blocks system. Something like this [Crash on EXT4-FS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851978/crash-on-ext4-fs). But fs is not read ony, reading also is not working.

**Investigation:**

1. Looks like problem not exists in Windows 10, because I used it several times just fine.
2. Looks like no problem with Kernel 5.8.x, but it still not usable without good AMD support (and no screen brightness)
3. Most common solution is to disable APSTE. It is not working for me
4. I found this thread https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208123, but they use WD 550 and I use recent SSD firmware (checked with WD Dashboard from Windows)
5. Latest Lenovo firmware from their Windows official app.
6. I also used fsck from live USB without success.
7. Checked RAM, CPU and SSD in Lenovo BIOS without success (all passes)

**System details:**

1. 2x16 Gb Ram
2. CPU: Ryzen 7 PRO 5850U
3. No secure boot, suspend setting for Linux in BIOS
4. Storage: WD Blue SN570 1TB, latest firmware, `fr: 234100WD` with 49 power cycles
5. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mitigations=off nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=200"` (sorry for missprints, I use it from another computer)

I don't know what to do next. I only have idea to replace this SSD with my old SATA SSD from my old laptop.

Comment: Unable to attach problem logs because they are not saved to journal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not a solution. But it works well.

I replaced SSD to my old Samsung PM981 (OEM vesrion of Samsung 970 EVO) from my previous laptop. And it works with recent kernel, 5.16.2 out of box, with APSTE enabled. Speeds are comparable.

Also I had many micro-freezes, they are also gone. I believe that it may be some problem with SSD firmware similar to SN550 [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208123).

I also need to mention, that this SN570 works with my old Latitide 7490 (i7-8650u) without this problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on the same system over 5 months, Here's what i found

- Disable Wi-Fi and using ethernet(or USB tether) is fine
- Disable SSD and boot from USB is fine
- Replace Wi-Fi chip with Intel 8265NGW is fine
- Replace Wi-Fi chip with Intel AX210 causes FS ro remount

I think that PCI between Wi-Fi and NVMe is something wrong on lenovo t14 gen2 AMD